# Changing URL for sub domained site

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I currently have a main site sitting at the server root and also a wordpress blog in a subdomain /blog

I'd like to be able to change the /blog to /industry-news but still redirect any links to the new uri structure so there are no dead links. Would I be able to do this using htaccess or is there a better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

This will help you to change wordpress URL:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL